# Light weight Branching strategy for a small team

Tags: version-control, merge, branching-and-merging

We are a small team (3 people) , that release once every 3 weeks or so. Ours is a service that is consumed by other customer facing services of the company. The project is in starting phase so we want to get the branching strategy right while we have the opportunity.
Here's what we have naively in mind, we will favour a trunk based development, and will create a feature branch only when we have to. We will have one other branch called the "CurrentRelease" that at any given time contains the currently deployed code. Towards the end of the sprint, after we hit Code complete we merge trunk to CurrentRelease do the final rounds of verification and release. We will have CI jobs running on trunk and also on CurrentRelease branch .
As we see it now there is small transition window , between the time we merge from trunk to CurrentRelease and the day we actually release , in which CurrentRelease branch doesn't exactly reflect the currently running code in production. Now if we were hit by an emergency bug in this time we , do not have a ready made branch wehre we can just go and check in the fix , run the CI and release. What could be a good solution for this ? 
  Should we actually have 2 CurrentRelease branches like a CurrentPreRelease and CurrentRelease. Initially CurrentRelease and CurrentPreRelease both contain the currently production deployed code and the order of merge for subsequent release  is `trunk -->(on the day of Code freeze) --> CurrentPreRelease --> (on the day of production deployment) CurrentRelease`.

Answer (score 0):

> What could be a good solution for this ?

Don't use SVN (it seems you are SVN-boys, at least for used terminology), branching|merging are a lot easier in DVCSes

Even with SVN - branch from `CurrentRelease@HEAD-1` (previous to mergeset of trunk) revision, commit fix, merge back to CurrentRelease, delete hotfix-branch (not mandatory, just for perfect-tree). Variation of solution is usage of rewritable (non-canonical way) tag CurrentRelease in addition to CurrentRelease branch - deployed version  always exist in CurrentRelease tag, from which you branch for hotfixes and to which you copy deployed CurrentRelease@HEAD (it can|have to be part of deploy procedure)